# Get the selected item's text and put them in a list

Tags: jquery

I know there are similar questions asked, I read all of those and my scenario is different.

I am building a Filter for a list of items. I have three sets of drop-downs in form of unordered lists (they look like drop-downs with some jQuery work). The drop-downs are the Categories that will be used for filtering the list of products.

when each item in the drop-down is clicked, a class 'selected' is being added to the item, here's an example:

```
<ul class="products-group">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="selected">Group 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Group 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Group 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="selected">Group 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Group 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in the above code, 'Group 1' and 'Group 4' are clicked (selected). When the Filter button is clicked, I want to output the selected items as **Active Filters** in a list format.

So I created a container like this:

```
<div id="active-filters"></div>
```

and this is my jquery:

```
$('.filter-btn').click(function () {
    var activeFilters = $('.products-group a.selected').text();
    $('#active-filters').html(activeFilters);
});
```

This works but it outputs all selected items as a long string of text. How do I separate each selected item and output them as li list item?

I looked up the .split() method but differentiating the words and separating them based on the space between them might not be the best. For example, Group 1 is two words and there's space between them but it is a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to loop through the selected elements and append an `<li>` for each.

```
var list = $("<ul>");
$('.products-group a.selected').each(function() {
    list.append($("<li>", { text: $(this).text() }));
});
$("#active-filters").empty().append(list);
```

Comment: there's an error in this line list.append($('<li>', { text: $(this).text(); })); I don't know what it is but the line is marked as red

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you, sir! :)

Comment: how to throw an anchor link inside the li with an id and # as href? This is the output that will work best for me: <li><a id="text" href="#">text</a></li>

Comment: Instead of `text: $(this).text()` use `html: $("<a>", {id: $(this).text(), href: "#", text: $(this).text() })`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending? Something like this

```
$.each(activeFilters, function(index, Group) {
  $('#newlist').append('<li><a href="#">'+Group+'</a></li>')
}
```

Comment: `activeFilters` is a string, not an array.

Comment: I did try this, I am getting an error I think due to data type and what @Barmar described earlier but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```js
     $('.filter-btn').click(function () {
    var activeFilters = $('.products-group>li>a.selected');
    LIST=document.createElement("ul");
    for(i=0;i<activeFilters.length;i++){
    LI=document.createElement("li");
    TXT=$(activeFilters[i]).text();
    $(LI).text(TXT);
    $(LIST).append(LI);
    }
    $('#active-filters').html(LIST);
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
 <ul class="products-group">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="selected">Group 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Group 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Group 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="selected">Group 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Group 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
 <div id="active-filters"></div>
 <a href="#" class="filter-btn">CLICK</a>
```